# Quanitative Skills and Reasoning Help.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This semester 10 students are taking physics, 25 students are taking both physics and math, and  45 Students are taking math. How many students are taking either physics or math or both? Which principle did you apply to answer this question?

I'm not understanding how to even begin to solve this, I've looked through our provided content with no luck.

Comment: Hint: think about these as sets. Draw a picture.

Comment: Do you mean physics {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} P&M {1,2,3....25} etc?

Comment: I suggest using a [truth table](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4761237/probability-of-student-not-taking-course/4762079?r=SearchResults&s=14%7C21.9605#4762079).

Comment: Stronger hint: draw a simple Venn diagram.

Comment: I believe the intent of the question is:  $10$ students are taking physics *and nothing else*, $25$ students are taking both physics and math, and $45$ students are taking math *and nothing else*.  Does that help?

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help! I was able to figure out the Venn diagram method and got my answer of 25.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Robert Shore, I am assuming you mean -

10 students are taking physics and nothing else, 25 students are taking both physics and math, and 45 students are taking math and nothing else.

Here's the Venn diagram for this.

[image]

So the number of students taking one or both of physics and math would be 10 + 25 + 45 = 80.